# Apple Music API - can't retrieve artists in search

Tags: ios, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm implementing the Apple Music API for my application.

I have a 1000-1200 record of artist names in my database and I want to match with Apple Music.

I'm using the search endpoint for that, but I couldn't retrieve any results for artists. Even the sample request in the documentation can't retrieve any results.

Sample request from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/Searchforresources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH58-SW1):

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=james+brown&limit=2&types=artists,albums
```

> Note: I'm using a developer token for authentication

Comment: Also discussed here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92466 but no solution yet I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you explain how you retrieved the Developer Token? It's giving me a 401 and I've followed the instructions!